# How can I programmatically add/remove models to a controller?

Tags: ember.js

This shouldn't be too hard.

I have a datepicker UI widget, and each time the user clicks on a month, I want to add or remove that month from the `MonthsController` (an `ArrayController`). The `MonthsController` is not associated with a route, so in my `ApplicationTemplate` I simply have

```
{{render months}}
```

A simplified version of my datepicker view is

```
App.DatepickerView = Ember.View.extend({
    click: function(e) {
      var id = $(this).datepicker().data('date').replace(" ", "-");
      this.get('controller.controllers.months').toggleMonth(id);
    }
});
```

and I handle the event in my `MonthsController`:

```
App.MonthsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    toggleMonth: function(id) {
        var month = App.Month.find(id),
            index = this.indexOf(month);
        if (index === -1) {
            this.pushObject(month);
        } else {
            this.removeAt(index);
        }
    }
});
```

I thought I had this working, but then I realized that `month` in the last snippet wasn't really an `App.Month`, it was just (I suppose) an anonymous object.

How can I programmatically add/remove models to a controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `App.Month.find(id)` will return a `promise`. If that month hasn't loaded yet you would also be loading this data from the server. You need to wrap your code in the promise's `then`.

```
toggleMonth: function(id) {
  var _this = this;

  App.Month.find(id).then(function(month) {
    var index = _this.indexOf(month);
    if (index === -1) {
        _this.pushObject(month);
    } else {
        _this.removeAt(index);
    }
  });
}
```