# Computed properties during ajax request

Tags: ember.js

I'm having trouble with a computed property.

It's a complex manipulation on an `ArrayController`. The problem is, Ember attempts to calculate it before the data has loaded. For example, part of it is

```
var counts = this.getEach('hours').forEach(function(hours) {
  var d = hours.find(function(_hour) {
    return +(_hour.date.substring(11, 13)) === 10;
  });
  return d.count;
});
```

I get an error because `this.getEach('hours')` returns something like

```
[ Array[24], undefined ]
```

while the AJAX request is loading, so the code breaks.

I'm sure others have run into this before - what's the solution?

**Update:** Here's how I get the data. When a user clicks a month in a view, I pass the clicked month's id to my `MonthsController`. It has a `toggleMonth` method:

```
App.MonthsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    toggleMonth: function(id) {
        var month = App.Month.find(id),
            index = this.indexOf(month);
        if (index === -1) {
            this.pushObject(month);
        } else {
            this.removeAt(index);
        }
    }
});
```

`App.Month.find(id)` sends the correct AjAX request + the data returns, but perhaps this is not the correct way to populate the months controller.

Also, this is happening within the `IndexRoute` (i.e. I have no separate route for the `MonthsController`. So, I never specify a model hook or `setupController` for the `MonthsController`.

Comment: Can you show, how you are sending the ajax and populating the hours array?

Comment: This would happen if you aren't returning a promise in the model hook. What does your route look like?

Comment: I think this may be resolved with this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891718/how-can-i-programmatically-add-remove-models-to-a-controller/17894539#17894539)?

Comment: You might want to provide more information about the hours field of the model.  On another note, computed properties update as the things they depend on update.  That being said, if the arraycontroller is empty, your code should be able to handle that state, if it's suddenly loaded with items it should be able to handle that.  If you don't specify setupController the default behavior is to set the model provided from the route to the controller.  If you don't specify a route, you need to assign the model to the controller through some other way (as you might be doing). Showing that would help.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks. Is it not enough that I push a model onto a controller? Do I need to assign it elsewhere?

Comment: Sherwin Yu makes reference to it down below, but a promise returned from the model hook will be resolved before it's sent to the setupController.  So as mentioned below, when is toggleMonth called?  Btw, toggleMonth isn't a computed property, it's just a function.

Comment: Right, I think I understand. I changed it to `App.Month.find(id).then(function() {...` and now it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The general approach to this problem is promises: asynchronous requests immediately return a promise, which is basically a promise of value, which can be resolved later down the line. All Ember models are promises behind the scenes. See [ember models as promises](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1642), and [How are Ember's Promises related to Promises in general, and specifically jQuery's Promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499316/how-are-embers-promises-related-to-promises-in-general-and-specifically-jquery)

Could you explain the context of the first block of code? What is `this` in `this.getEach('hours').forEach` and when is that block executed?

Comment: It's the array controller that's storing the models. I think @DarshanSawardekar answered the question in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891718/how-can-i-programmatically-add-remove-models-to-a-controller/17894539#17894539). The trouble I'm having is knowing how much I need to do on my own, and how much Ember does for me. I knew Ember models were promises, but I didn't know if I had to call `.then` on it, or if Ember would know not to recalculate the property until the promise was resolved.